(Why) didn't the "fountain of justice" flow through Governors-General?
Nowadays both the Australian and Canadian governments agree that their (respective) Governor-General (henceforth GG) belongs to two branches of government: both executive and legislative.
Interestingly enough, in both of those countries, the GG is not considered to be part of the 3rd branch--the judiciary--even though in the UK itself, the Monarch is still considered the "fountain of justice". OTOH:

The separation of courts from the monarch in person can be dated back to the famous Case of Prohibitions in 1607. James I wanted to decide a property dispute. He considered that there was no need to know any law to dispense justice. He was endowed by God with all the qualities that were needed and could apply his sense of justice. As Lord Burnett explains, Sir Edward Coke, then Chief Justice of the Court of Common Pleas, disagreed, saying, ‘the King in his own person cannot adjudge any case, either criminal – as treason, felony etc, or betwixt party and party; but this ought to be determined and adjudged in some court of justice, according to the Law and Custom of England.’

Nonetheless, I'm still curious why the "fountain of justice" is not (and perhaps was never)  considered to formally flow through Governor-Generals, as representatives of the Monarch in "the colonies" (now, the Commonwealth). Is it simply because all such GG roles were established after 1607? Some other (historical or maybe political philosophy) reasons?

Aside, one of the annoying things about Wikipedia's article on GG is that it doesn't even say when the first such post was formally established. I guess I could ask that as a separate Q.

One might also ask if Viceroys were any different in this respect (of channeling or not) the fountain of justice.

From your first link, the table at the bottom, states in the "How achieved" is "Selected by the prime minister". This means that is chosen by politics and then by executive and legislative power. If the GG had also Judiciary, it means to overthrow constitutional separation of duty.
Different thing if "how achieved" was "chosen by monarch", in that case you would have been right
(my guessing)

@DanM: not necessarily. The GGs could simply have analogous powers to a nowadays/post-1607 monarch of appointing King's or Queen's Counsel in their colony/territory, without the GG dispensing justice themselves, personally. (This is in part why I quoted that para, on [practical] separation of powers.)

the key (still, from my point of view) is who choose the GG. IF GG is chosen by Queen/King, then she/he is a full proxy of Queen/King, while if she/he is not chosen by the monarch, is not a full proxy.
by the way, while it clear who choose the GG in Australia, in Canada is "appointed by the Monarch on the advice of the Prime Minister"; it makes wonder if there have been  GG appointed by Monarch different form what Prime Minister advised

Can you say what might have been different, had the fountain of justice flowed through Governors-General?

Untangling this kind of history is tricky because Canadian (and possibly Australian) patriation was not a one-time thing, but developed gradually as each country untangled multiple systems of dependency from Britain. The Governor General itself is not even originally a British office:

The office of Governor General is the oldest continuous institution
in Canada and is an unbroken link with the early days of our country’s
recorded history. Samuel de Champlain was appointed the first
governor of New France in 1627 and was followed by seventeen
French governors until 1760. From then until 1867, a total of
twenty-one British governors and governors general held office
in Canada.

But let's pop open the British North America Act of 1867 which turned a hodgepodge of legal and government systems into one thing:

III. 9. The Executive Government and Authority of and over Canada is hereby declared to continue and be vested in the Queen.


IV. 17. There shall be One Parliament for Canada, consisting of the Queen, an Upper House styled the Senate, and the House of Commons.

The monarch - and through them, the Governor General - is part of the Executive because that is where executive power is vested, and part of the legislature because that is where the monarch sits.

VII. 96. The Governor General shall appoint the Judges of the Superior, District, and County Courts in each Province, except those of the Courts of Probate in Nova Scotia and New Brunswick.


VII. 101. The Parliament of Canada may, notwithstanding anything in this Act, from Time to Time, provide for the Constitution, Maintenance, and Organization of a General Court of Appeal for Canada, and for the Establishment of any additional Courts for the better Administration of the Laws of Canada.

The monarch is not part of the judicial system...in Canada. However, as their role as King-in-Council, the monarch presides over the Judicial Committee of the Privy Council which was essentially the Supreme Court for all territories and dominions of the Crown. So while the judiciary flowed up to the monarch it did not do so through the Governor General, but directly from the provincial or federal Courts to the sovereign.
As patriation progressed (in fits and starts) Canada became dissatisfied with this situation (a book-length topic but start with Chapter 2 here) and eventually ended it in a fittingly halting way:

In 1939, the constitutionality of these
measures was examined by the Supreme Court in the form of a
reference put to the Court by the Governor in Council. The
Court held that Parliament could proceed to eliminate all appeals
to the Privy Council. This decision was subsequently appealed
to the Privy Council, which was unable to hear the case until
after the Second World War. In 1946, however, the Supreme
Court's opinion was affirmed and Parliament was allowed to
abolish all appeals to the Privy Council. This process was
completed in 1949, at which time a new era began for the
Supreme Court of Canada as that of the court of last resort in the
nation

As a result, the judiciary ended up "king-less". No one bothered to reinsert the monarchy when the constitution was patriated in 1982; in fact the Supreme Court Act is not even part of the constitution.

To add a bit to the missing link angle: the JCPC had empire-, later commonwealth-wide authority: "At its height, the Judicial Committee was said to be the court of final appeal for over a quarter of the world. [...] Canada abolished Privy Council appeals in 1949, India and South Africa in 1950, Australia in 1986, and New Zealand in 2003." (Wikipedia)

Another interesting point, which is probably not a coincidence, time-wise: the JCPC was established in 1833, superseding the (1696) ACPC. In the same year (1833),  the first Governor General of India was given this title. Like with the ACPC/JCPC, the GG institution [of India] existed under other names before.

Another relevant point is that the GG of India was granted (that 1833 year) one-man legislative power for the colony. So he essentially had real executive and legislative powers back then. I suppose giving the same person (who was not a jurist) also any kind of judicial powers was deemed too much given 1607.

Actually, it wasn't quite a one-man rule in India because the GG had a Council of 2-5 others (beginning 1773 or so, but size varied over time) with legislative & executive votes till 1861, when it was significantly expanded
and also split between the legislative and executive councils. However, the 'judicature' was already separate since 1773.

OTOH, there was this nugget: "The Viceroy was allowed, under the provisions of the [1861] Act, to overrule the council on affairs if he deemed it necessary." I guess that partly explains the title being then [well, more precisely, starting 1858] upgraded from GG to Viceroy. Oddly enough, the Secretary for India put it on passage "the [1861] act is a great experiment [...] that the old autocratic government cannot stand unmodified is indisputable". I guess overruling the council[s] was deemed something of a reserve power, not be exercised commonly, by the Viceroy.

@gottrolledtoomuchthisweek Yes, such reserve powers seem to be in the DNA of Commonwealth governance, see for example the notwithstanding clause as a modern example

The latter is a power of Parliament though.
